# PHP + Codeigniter + MySQL -> unable to perform db operations

Tags: php, android, codeigniter

This is my first post here.I am an android developer and my server stuff is always in php.
I am using the PHP + codeigniter + MySQL based architechture to perform some basic database operation like insert,read,update.
To test out the scripts functioning I am firing the script url with proper parameters in my browser , but the issue is the insert function is not working

URL To fire for insertion
***www.[xxxxxx].com/[xxxx]/device/checkdevice/test/test/test***

device.php

```
function checkdevice($did=false)
        {
                if($_POST){
                        $did = $_REQUEST['did'];
                        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
                        $number = $_REQUEST['number'];
                        $res = $this->device_model->insertid($did, $name, $number);
                        return;
                }
        }
```

device_model.php

```
function insertid($id=false,$name=false,$number=false)
        {
           $res = $this->db->get_where('tbl_device', array('clm_device_id'=>$id,'clm_device_name'=>$name,'clm_device_number'=>$number))->num_rows;
           if($res==0){
           $date = date("Y-m-d");
           $this->db->insert('tbl_device', array('clm_registered'=>$date, 'clm_device_id'=>$id,'clm_device_name'=>$name,'clm_device_number'=>$number));
                }

                return;
        }
```

database.php // my database connection works ok

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;


$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'xxxxx';
$db['default']['password'] = 'xxxx';
$db['default']['database'] = 'xxxx';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE; //Tried making FALSE but doesnt work
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE; //Tried making FALSE but doesnt work
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: no specific error just a blank page

Comment: Try to change `ENVIRONMENT` to `development` in your project root index.php file.

Comment: its already in development mode ->define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');

Comment: Add first line in index.php `error_report(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to load your model and get query string data direct in function parameter and make a echo to check what you get after return.

device.php

```
function checkdevice($did='', $name='', $number='') {
  echo $did;
  echo $name;
  echo $number;
  // if you get values remove post variable and pass these else try with post vars
 // $did = $this->input->post('did');
  //$name = $this->input->post('name');
  //$number = $this->input->post('number');
  $this->load->model('device_model');
  $res = $this->device_model->insertid($did, $name, $number);
  if($res) {
    echo 'success';
  }
  else {
    echo 'fail';
  }
}
```

device_model.php

```
function insertid($id=false,$name=false,$number=false) {
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->where(array('clm_device_id'=>$id,'clm_device_name'=>$name,'clm_device_number'=>$number));
  $query = $this->db->get('tbl_device');
  if($query->num_rows > 0){ 
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $this->db->insert('tbl_device', array('clm_registered'=>$date, 'clm_device_id'=>$id,'clm_device_name'=>$name,'clm_device_number'=>$number));
    return $this->db->insert_id();
  }
  else{ 
    return false ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding your code and firing the url now shows ->                      404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.

Comment: check updated make sure you have values for $did, $name etc in function try with an cho

Comment: @RakeshSharma I think you need to change `checkdevice($arg1,$arg2,$arg3)` and remove $this->input->post.

Comment: so this is what i get now->A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: models/device_model.php

Line Number: 10

Comment: Have you loaded the database library in `application/config/autoload.php` ?

Comment: fixed this , some columns were missing in concerned table